# How to create and run Dialog from Middleware with Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

## Question

How can I conditionally create and run a Dialog from
middleware without breaking the bot?

### Context

I'm using the [dotnetcore/13.core-bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot).

I have a setup to run a custom spellchecking Middleware. I am trying to create a dialog from Middleware so that **after the user types some misspelled input** and *ONLY* when two or more spellcheck suggestions are found, the user gets the possible sentence interpretations and chooses from a HeroCard or similar.

From my middleware `SpellcheckMiddleware.cs`, `myDialog.RunAsync(...)` runs a dialog, however, after the middleware exits `onTurnAsync()`, I get a fatal error: **`"An item with the same key has already been added"`**. That error occurs when the bot tries to continue `MainDialog` from [MainDialog.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs) which is the dialog that was setup in [Startup.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Startup.cs#L47-L51).

**Bot emulator visual**

[image]

### Error capture within Visual Studio

(**`"An item with the same key has already been added"`**)

[image]

---

## My code

The only thing I have changed from the sample code is creating these two files, one defines the dialog that resolves a spellcheck with multiple suggestions, and one that is middleware that should run the spellcheck dialog.

`SpellcheckMiddleware.cs:`

```cs
public class SpellCheckMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private readonly ConversationState conversationState;

    public SpellCheckMiddleware(
        IConfiguration configuration, 
        ConversationState conversationState)
    {
        this.conversationState = conversationState;
    }

    public async Task OnTurnAsync(
        ITurnContext turnContext, 
        NextDelegate next,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {            
        
        # Fake suggestions
        List<List<String>> suggestions = new List<List<String>>{ 
            new List<String>{'Info', 'Olympics'},
            new List<String>{'Info', 'Olympia'},
        };

        SpellcheckSuggestionsDialog myDialog = new SpellcheckSuggestionsDialog(suggestions);            

        await myDialog.RunAsync(
            turnContext, 
            conversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), 
            cancellationToken);
            
        await next(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`SpellcheckSuggestionsDialog.cs:`

```cs
class SpellcheckSuggestionsDialog : ComponentDialog
{
    // Create a prompt that uses the default choice recognizer which allows exact matching, or number matching.
    public ChoicePrompt SpellcheckPrompt { get; set; }
    public WaterfallDialog WaterfallDialog { get; set; }
    List<string> Choices { get; set; }

    internal SpellcheckSuggestionsDialog(
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> correctedSentenceParts)
    {
        SpellcheckPrompt = new ChoicePrompt(
            nameof(ChoicePrompt), 
            validator: null, 
            defaultLocale: null);
        WaterfallDialog = new WaterfallDialog(
            nameof(WaterfallDialog), 
            new WaterfallStep[]{
                SpellingSuggestionsCartesianChoiceAsync,
                EndSpellingDialogAsync
            });

        AddDialog(SpellcheckPrompt);
        AddDialog(WaterfallDialog);
        InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);

        // Get all possible combinations of the elements in the list of list. Works as expected.
        var possibleUtterances = correctedSentenceParts.CartesianProduct();

        // Generate a choices array with the flattened list
        Choices = new();
        foreach (var item in possibleUtterances) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item.JoinStrings(" "));
            Choices.Add(item.JoinStrings(" "));                        
        }
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SpellingSuggestionsCartesianChoiceAsync(
        WaterfallStepContext stepContext, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
            SpellcheckPrompt.Id, 
            new PromptOptions()
            {
                Choices = ChoiceFactory.ToChoices(Choices),
                RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("Did you mean...?"),
                Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Did you mean...?"),
                Style = ListStyle.HeroCard
            });
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> EndSpellingDialogAsync(
        WaterfallStepContext stepContext, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Overriding text sent using the choosen correction.
        stepContext.Context.TurnState.Add("CorrectionChoice", stepContext.Result);
        var choosen_correction = stepContext.Context.TurnState.Get<string>("CorrectionChoice");
        stepContext.Context.Activity.Text = choosen_correction;

        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(null, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: *I could not make it work from middleware back then.* What I did was add a new dialog as part of the waterfall dialog steps defined in your main dialog constructor. This new dialog autocorrects silently if only one spellcheck suggestion exists, otherwise, it does `return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(spellcheckResolverDialog.Id)` to initiate another dialog that lets the user choose a suggestion. It should be designed so that it flows naturally with the user interaction.

Comment: It may be possible to do it from middleware, but I believe that the conclusion I reached was that middleware was not designed with the intent of overriding the waterfall dialog flow with new dialogs; rather, it was designed perhaps for logging, user validation, data storage, or similar.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2022, there is no sample from Microsoft showing dialogs being spawned from middleware, so **that is likely not the intended way to use the framework.** It may be possible, but then you're in a sense going against the framework, which is never advisable.

In order to have a dialog that provides spellcheck suggestions when the user types with a typo, I suggest you make that dialog part of logic specified in the WaterFall Dialog steps in [MainDialog.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L31-L36).

```cs
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
{
    IntroStepAsync,
    SpellcheckStep, //new step to force user to choose a spellcheck suggestions
    ActStepAsync,
    FinalStepAsync,
}));
```

This comes with the drawback that if you need to spellcheck multiple user inputs in the conversation, then you will need to add multiple spellcheck steps, each customized to handle the input expected at the matching point in the conversation steps.